# making AppCompatEditText hint to visible in 2 or 3 lines

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-appcompat

I am using AppCompatEditText in my app but the hint is too large is there any way to make it visible in 2 or 3 lines.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/txt_stu_passed_eight"
                        style="@style/TextAppearence.TextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_stu_passed_eight"
                            style="@style/customEdittext"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/how_many_of_them_passed_school"
                            android:inputType="number" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

here is the screen shot of edittext :
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try using the tag minLines inside your AppCompatEditText?

Comment: but I want multi lines for hint not for the input text